# Using an Unsigned dll in clickonce

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I have a bunch of unsigned 3rd party dlls that i want to download to the client only on demand. The issue is i am not able to sign these dlls. Is there any way to sign a 3rd party dll which is un managed. I tried "signer" tool but that doesn't support unsigned dll.

Comment: Why do you think you need to sign the dll's? If you are signing the whole deployment, that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign them digitally but if you talking SN.exe - no. Yes, you can sign 3rd party dlls with your digital certificate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388170%28VS.85%29.aspx